# Should I change the "behaviour" of a page because IE is not able to run some actions?

Tags: jquery, security, internet-explorer, ssl

Let me clarify this question. I am creating a simple web page for a particular event. The client has a domaing/hosting without SSL. This page has info about the event and a registration form for the event, which uses `jQuery` (for validation), `PHP` (for sending emails) and `Parse.com` (for uploading the users info to a DB).

The page works perfectly on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, iOS and Android. But it does not work in IE (not even in IE 11) unless the security options allows *everything* (scripting, etc.). Besides, (I'm not so sure here) `Parse.com` functions do not work on IE without SSL.

I told the client and he said that he could not get an SSL certificate and he would not mind telling the IE users to try with a different browser.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea having in mind all the context and the client conditions?
2. Assuming this, I was thinking about this approach on the code:

#### HTML

```
<div id="ie-info">
    <p>Use a different browser...</p>
</div>

<div id="form">
    <p>Here comes the form</p>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
function isExplorer() {
    if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Explorer") > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(navigator.appName == "MSIE") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (isExplorer()){ //Si usas Chrome poner "Netscape"
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("ie-info").style.display = "none";
}
```

[This looks pretty "*basic*" since I do not want IE to go crazy if it finds some scripting]

In this case I am *changing the behaviour* of my page *because* of IE, since I have two `div`s on the page now, and depending on the user's browser, it hides some `div` or the other. I do not know if this is a **good approach** or could I do something else?

I do not have much experience, so I would like to know an opinion from someone that may have faced these kind of problems before.

Comment: I would use http://caniuse.com/ and make my desicions after that. It will be a pain for you to manage updates with the approach you are suggesting.

Comment: What is failing in IE but not in every other browser?

Comment: `Parse.com` calls, if scripting is enabled on browser. Both `Parse.com` calls and any other functions if it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've personally experienced this problem before and here are a couple of guidelines which might help you.

> 1. Check the percentage of users using Internet Explorer. If it's significant (e.g. > 50%), you might need to reconsider your strategy of letting them use a new browser. Otherwise your approach should be okay.
> 2. Depending on your application and the data it handles, you might really need to get an SSL certificate. For most e-commerce sites, this is a minimum even if you're not using a third party like Parse.com which requires SSL.
> 3. If you really need to support Internet Explorer, you have to convince your client to support SSL (if it's really required)

Comment: I agree. Since this is going to be an info web page for a specific event, I would say it is ok that we will not use SSL and set not using IE as a requirement. Thanks for the info!